# How to switch between Korean and English keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I am using Windows 10 and right now I have English and Korean keyboards installed and two switch between the two I use the hotkey: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

The problem with this is that it switches to Hangul (Korean) language, but the keyboard still stays English. I then have to switch by pressing <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get to proper Hangul keyboard OR use my mouse to click the Eng/Kor button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear but what I understand is that you want to change the keyboard shortcut from <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. I hope this link helps:
https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d

Comment: No. I want to be able to switch from Korean to English and backwards with one hotkey, not two (or one and a mouseclick).

Right now:

Win+Shift switches Language (Keyboard, etc.)
Right-Alt+Shift switches characters within that language (i.e. Korean has Eng/Kor alphabet).

Answer (score 1):

window11  IME

- for hangul : <kbd>left shift</kbd> to toggle english/chinese within the hangul setting
- for korean <kbd>right alt</kbd> to toggle english korean within the korean setting